# do any of the C# RSS reader support reading custom fields

Tags: c#, rss, parsing

I have rss that has a number of other custom fields. do any of the c# libraries (RSS.NEt, etc) support reading these fields?  i can't seem to find any reference to this.

what is the easier way to parse XML from an RSS feed and include customer fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up changing the RSS.net source code to take in all custom fields as a big Dictionary  a few lines changes and now i am all set.

Answer (score 1):

RSS feeds have a well defined structure. You can use `XPath` to get the fields you need. 
[Here's a sample introduction](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333) and here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just do the deserialization yourself. Throw together a few classes with attributes from System.XML.Serialization and you're set. Then you don't have to mess around with existing libraries or XPath.